# Is this bad design / a violation of model-view-controller?

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I'm writing an app that connects to a server and fetches a list of images, then downloads them and displays them in a grid.

Part one of this process is done by a client class I have that connects to the server and asks for the list of image URLs. I do this in my view controller and pass it in to my view.

Part two is done by an image cache class I've written which takes each image URL and checks if the app has downloaded it and stored it previously. If so, it gets the image from the filesystem and returns it. Otherwise it asynchronously downloads the image and stores it.

The way I'm doing things now, my view controller fetches the list of image identifiers and passes them into my view. The view then creates image views for each image and fills them with placeholder images, then asks the image cache for each image and fills in the images as they are downloaded.

Is it bad design for my view's draw function itself to have this logic for downloading the images? It feels kind of like a violation of MVC because my view is doing work to get the data it's supposed to display. However, the actual networking is being done elsewhere (in the image cache class) and is abstracted away such that the view is simply calling `[ImageCache getImageForIdentifier:... completionHandler:...]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, A view class should not make any network calls. Views can just communicate with Controller to get the data which needs to be displayed. So,

1. Your controller job is to get the URL or Images.
2. Have a Model class which has collection of all Images which needs to be displayed later. Add this model class reference into your controller.
3. Controller should check cache and populate your model class. If the cache doesn't have image, then your controller should download those images for your model.
4. Expose a public method from controller to populate your view from model object.

---

My go would be to create three different classes,

1. ImageCahce = Model class
2. ImageCollection = Model class
3. ImageDataController = Controller class.

ImageCache class stores already downloaded images, may be in CoreData. ImageCollection class will get populated every time from ImageCache and later of more new images needed then from ImageDataController.

Comment: I guess the problem is I'm confusing myself over whether my image cache is a model or a controller. I think your approach is better for my needs though; treat the image cache as a controller and create a model class to place in between my view and my controller here. Thanks!

Comment: ImageCache is a model class, and ImageDataController could be the potentially controller for you.

Comment: I see, that makes more sense.

Comment: I ended up doing pretty much what you suggested. I made a model class to represent an image and its identifier and some other information, and have another class for an image collection, and a controller that populates the collection using the cache. It ended up being a lot cleaner than the previous implementation. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ImageCache` class is an example of a Model level class. It has no knowledge of any UI. Good MVC would say that a View class, like your grid view, should *never* talk directly to a Model class. That's what the Controller is for.

A cleaner implementation would be to let the controller use the ImageCache to do the downloading and update the grid view as it goes. This moves some business logic out of the grid view class, and leaves it to worry about presentation only.